# Did Walter White's poor choices lead to his downfall?

Tags: character, breaking-bad

Walter and Skyler were about to get divorced. But Skyler being calculating and manipulative knew that without money she would not be able to survive, so reconciled with Walter.  He happily obliged in spite of Skyler's previous humiliation and coldness towards him.

Walter could have had better chances of success of providing for his family being away from the present city and restarting his business someplace else as a complete unknown personality (with or without Gus).

In this way,

> Hank would have never caught hold of the book which Gale had presented to Walter.

**Does this show that Walter was weak minded in spite of being smart and his poor choices got to him again here?**

Comment: I don't think your first paragraph is correct... Skyler didn't stay with Walter because she wanted money. She stayed with him mostly for the sake of not wanting the kids to find out, and also because of her own confused feelings towards Walt.

Comment: GendoIkari-I do not remember the episode name but there is a scene where Skyler comes across the bag of cash that Walt has hidden in his closet. The look on her face said it all . Money seduced her.

Comment: Your assumption hidden by the spoiler assumes that Walter values the mentioned item enough to take it.  I'm not sure he cared that much for it as it's rarely brought up in episodes

Comment: @moonrika *"The look on her face said it all . Money seduced her."* ... No ... no that is a sad, confused interpretation :/

Comment: @gabe3886- Walter did go back to check on that book in the bathroom once he came to know that Hank started behaving weirdly. Cared enough to remember that it is a potential give away.

Comment: @Ghoti and Chips True it is a sad interpretation.. What I hated was that initially Skyler was agitated with Walter's secret business, the money and the threat to the family which was in every sense very right from her part. Once she started to know the amount of money it is generating and Walter getting away with it, she thew away all the righteousness and jumped in it.

Answer (score 12):

**It shows what Walter is always all about : Pride**

Throughout the entire show (at least past season 1) **Walter has more than enough money to provide for his family**. His deals with Gus makes him a millionaire but **he still won't quit** and he manipulates Jesse into staying with him by removing all distractions (read women) so that they can keep doing what they do best : Chemistry.

**Walter White is an incredibly talented chemist** and yet he is just a small teacher in high school. **A nobody**. But he deserves more, right? Past a certain point in the series, **Walter fades away and Heisenberg remains**. The famous drug lord who is the only one able to make blue meth.

**If Heisenberg was to go away then his name dies out** and he will be forgotten and that'd be unacceptable.

In a way you are right "**his poor choices got to him again here**" but not because he was weak minded but because he was too stubborn, selfish and proud.

Edit: It is basically like cucking your neighbor. The best part is that it's right in front of his (read Hank's) eyes and yet he doesn't catch you. That's where the thrill comes from : being on the edge

Comment: Hank, not Frank :) I assume.

Comment: Yeah I misrembered his name ><

Comment: "It is basically like cucking your neighbour" CRINGE ALERT

Comment: Abandon ship, women and children first !

Answer (score 1):

People like Walter White are not made, nor do they come about by conscious choices they make.

People like Walter White are formed, by circumstances and forces outside of their control.

What started it all? His cancer. What compelled him to persevere? The 727k he needed to insure his family's stability after he passes.

But even then, he continued on. Why? Because there's no greater feeling in the world than being really really good at something, and making a lot of money from it. Couple that with the adage that the sweetest fruit comes from the forbidden tree...

There's a theory by Kenneth Burke(I think) that explains how identity is finely shaped and well defined in conflict and challenge. Walter White fits this theory quite well.

But to call his rise and fall little more than "bad choices" is reductive. It ignores the complex character that is Walter White.

His story is outstanding and fascinating, because I think every one of us who saw the show and enjoyed saw the truth: what he went thru could have happened to any one of us.

Comment: Except we're not genius chemists so we'd have just laid down and executed part 1 of 3 : accept your death